# What is SVN client for unix

Tags: unix, svn

Friends need Quick help..
My project has SVN repository and we checkout/checkin code from our windows system. So far we are good.

Now I have to checkout my SVN code on unix box and build it there directly.. My problem is

1. I do know how to find, if my Unix box has SVN installed. I am searching for 'SVN' folder on root dir.
2. If SVN client is not installed then what is that SVN client I should install.

Note: After SVN install, I know the command line checkout process..Pls suggest, I could not find on google.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic here. If you have trouble understanding an SVN operation, we'd be happy to help you (See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for some tips). For this question, you should try at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: I did not asked about Software, but my question was to know about SVN and how its client are installed on a box.

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply type

`svn help`

If it replies, `svn` is installed.

2. otherwise for most *nix distributions you can install it with `apt-get`:

`sudo apt-get install subversion`

If the *nix system has no package manager, you can download the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/subversion), and run

```
./configure && make
```

In the root folder of the downloaded repository.

---

You can checkout a repository by running

```
svn checkout <url>
```

in the command line in a folder where you want to store the project. Run

```
svn help
```

for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got it resolved. I was not on right path where it was installed. Once I found the path all commands are working..